# "soft deleting" in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have some code to soft delete records in an application using EF5. My "deletable" class implements ISoftDelete that simply says the implementor must have a bool Deleted property.

When my users click delete I call DbContext..Remove(entity)

This clears any properties that bind to parent entities to null(If my parent has a collection of my deletable entity!).

In my DbContext I override the SaveChanges method to find any deleted entities and if they implement my ISoftDelete interface I set the state to modified rather than deleted and set its Deleted property to true to mark as deleted. My issue is that the properties holding references to parents are null.

Investigations seem to point to ApplyOriginalValues but as my values aren't public properties but are created for me by virtue of being a child in a collection, I am struggling to implement. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you used another approach it may be easier.
Using a repository and Unit of Work fascade pattern rather than directly calling EF Context, means you control actions more easily.
The unit of work class  controls the savechanges actions.
 The repository class controls CRUD, GetLists etc..

```
   public class RepositoryBase<TPoco> : IRespository {

       public RepositoryBase(DbContext context) { Context = context; }
          //... CRUD methods....
          public bool Remove(TPoco poco) {
                   if (typeof ISoftDelete).IsAssignableFrom(Typeof(TPoco)){
                       // proceed with modify actions
                   }
                   else {
                          Context.Set<TPoco>().Remove(poco);
                   }
          }
   }

   public class Luw : ILuw{
         // ....
          public IRepositoryBase<TPoco> GetRepository<TPoco>() where TPoco : ???{
              return (new RepositoryFactory<TPoco>().GetRepository(Context));
         }

  public MuCustomResult  Commit() {
          .... any special context manipulation before save
          myCustomResultRecordsAffected = Context.SaveChanges();

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're probably right Phil. Don't know how much effort is going to be involved but is definitely the correct approach. Cheers for the advice, gonna scour the internet for a nice simple EF repository example/tutorial.

Comment: If you have access to pluralsight i know there are some good examples.  But it costs to join.